# Ajax calendar navigation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have next and previous links in the html:

```
<a href="/event-sort/calendar/2009/9/sports/">prev</a>
<a href="/event-sort/calendar/2009/11/sports/">next</a>
```

When they are clicked, I want the page to make an ajax call to load a PHP script that will update the calendar's html.

Now when the calendar updates, the arrows have been removed and added to the dom again, so I'm having trouble binding these events.

This is what I have now:

```
function url_to_array(string)
    {
        var url = string;
        var url_array = url.split('/');
        return url_array;
    }

function update_cal(evt)
    {
        var url_array = url_to_array(evt.data);
            
        $('#master-calendar').css({
            background:'url(/images/ajax-load.gif) no-repeat left top',
            height:'600px'
        }).html('');
        
        $.get('/ajax_events.php',
            {
                view:url_array[2],
                year:url_array[3],
                month:url_array[4],
                category:url_array[5]
            },
            function(returned_data)
            {
                $('#content').html(returned_data);
                var element_id = $(evt.target).attr('id');
                var element_href = $('#' + element_id).attr('href');
                $('#' + element_id).unbind('click', update_cal).bind('click', element_href, update_cal);
            }
        );
        
        evt.preventDefault();
    }   

// Document Ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    var prev_link = $('#cal_nav_previous').attr('href');
    $('#cal_nav_previous').bind('click', prev_link, update_cal);
    
    var next_link = $('#cal_nav_next').attr('href');
    $('#cal_nav_next').bind('click', next_link, update_cal);

});// End Document Ready
```

I really would like to use the one `update_cal` function for both my next and previous buttons.

I wanted the calendar to be accessible with js, that's the reason for the hrefs and date numbers in the urls, any help would be appreciated.

I had experimented with jQuery live events, but didn't have much success.

Can I bind the `update_cal` function to both the next and previous links at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are several questions here, so I´ll try to answer a few of them.

**To avoid the default behaviour of the links** you can use jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Of course you have to specify the right links...

**To pass a variable from the link to your script**, you can use the rel attribute:

```
<a href="/event-sort/calendar/2009/9/sports/" rel="200909">prev</a>
<a href="/event-sort/calendar/2009/11/sports/" rel="200911">next</a>
```

and read the rel attribute with jquery.

**To automatically bind the events**, you can put the bind part in the ajax_events.php script

That seems about it, or am I missing something?

By the way, I was trying to numerate my answers, but that messes up the code, so bold it is...

Comment: I'm able to pass the var in from the href of the link, then I split the string into an array and pass it to the ajax php script as get variables

I would prefer not to have to put any event bindings in the ajax php script, because then I have inline scripts in the page

keeping all the js in one external file is best for me

I updated my code above, will it work to bind new events in the ajax callback function?

Comment: ok I updated the code above and now the he binding is working for repeated previous clicks, but if I click on next the page refreshes

Comment: ultimately what I did was create a function that binds the events to the links, and call the function both on document ready and as an ajax callback

so the events get added to the new ajax elements after they are loaded

that seems to work

thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, yes, I´ve done that on a few projects as well, seems like a decent compromise.